# Maximizing a functional (integral)

Tags: calculus

I wish to find the maximum possible value for
$$ \int_0^1  x f(x) - \int_0^x f(y) dy dx $$

where $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is weakly increasing.

My conjecture is that the solution is $\frac{1}{4}$, e.g. when
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x 
\geq \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & x < \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}, $$

but I am stuck terms of finding a proof. Perhaps I need to set the "functional derivative" to zero? How would one do this in this setting?

Comment: Am I crazy or does the expression evaluate to $\frac{1}{6}$ for $f(x) = x$?

Comment: yes you're right, I corrected the question before seeing your comment

Answer (score 1):

The second integral can be written as
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(y)dy\ dx = \int_0^1\int_y^1 f(y) dx\ dy 
= \int_0^1 (1-y)f(y) dy,
$$
so the functional to be maximized is equal to
$$
\int_0^1 (2x-1) f(x) dx.
$$
This suggests that $f(x) = \chi_{(1/2,1)}(x)$ gives the maximum among increasing functions, which can be verified easily. In fact, this $f$ realizes the maximum of the integral for all integrable functions with values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: thank you! what is $\chi$ in the last line?

Comment: characteristic function of a set, i.e., $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, $=0$ if $x\not\in A$. It is equal to your guess of the best $f$.

Comment: Thanks! So (not to be pedantic, just to make sure I understand) you meant $\chi_{(1/2,1)}$, yes?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: sorry,  one last question: could you please exclaim the last step in your first line of equalities? why does $\int_y^1 f(x) dx = (1-y) f(y)$?

Comment: was a typo: should have been $f(y)$ all the time.